# Devise Rails & Admin_Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise with my Rails 4 app.

I have the following in my `user.rb` model:

```
def send_admin_mail
  AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
end

def send_user_welcome_mail
  AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_access(user).deliver
end
```

The first method sends me an email when a new user registers. The aim is for the second method to send a welcome email to the new user.  The first method works. The second raises an issue with 'no_method_error' (undefined method email in my callbacks controller).

My callback controller has the following:

```
def linkedin
  @user = User.find_for_linkedin_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  if @user.persisted?
    @user.send_admin_mail
    @user.send_user_welcome_mail

    redirect_to root_path, :event => :authentication
    # sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
    # set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "LinkedIn") if is_navigational_format?
  else
    session["devise.linkedin_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

My admin_mailer has:

```
def new_user_waiting_for_approval(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: "myemailaddress@gmail.com", from: "myemailaddress@gmail.com", 
  subject: "Registration Request #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name} <#{user.email}>")
end

def new_user_waiting_for_access(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: user.email, from: "myemailaddress@gmail.com", subject: "Welcome to Co #{user.first_name}")
end
```

I'm wondering whether I need to replace user with current_user to make use of the devise method or maybe whether some variation on {} and/or "" is required around the user.email in the second method?? I've tried a few different variations and combinations but haven't had any success.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the exact error trace you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def send_user_welcome_mail
  AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_access(user).deliver
end
```

should be replaced with

```
def send_user_welcome_mail
  AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_access(self).deliver
end
```

user -> self

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. When I try it, I get this error: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x007f6058845ca0>:0x007f60578287f0>). The logs refer me to this line in my callback controller:  @user.send_user_welcome_mail

Comment: why are you using user in your view? it should be @user.